# No Run Results found after runner class in Karate framework

Tags: java, api, automated-tests, cucumber, karate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHBY3.png)

I have just followed the details given in https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/api-testing-with-karate-framework/

**Runner class:**

**package Karate.KarateTestScriptsSample;**

**import org.junit.runner.RunWith;**

**import com.intuit.karate.junit4.Karate;**

@RunWith(Karate.class)

public class TestRunner {

}

Feature file used:

Feature: fetching User Details

Scenario: testing the get call for User Details

Given url 'https://reqres.in/api/users/2'

When method GET

Then status 200

============================================================

**Pom.XML**

4.0.0

```
<groupId>Karate</groupId>
<artifactId>KarateTestScriptsSample</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>KarateTestScriptsSample</name>
<!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
<url>http://www.example.com</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
        <artifactId>karate-apache</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
        <artifactId>karate-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
</dependencies>

<build>

    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </testResource>
        
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
   
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven 
            defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
        <plugins>
            <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

========================================================

Project view:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvDhX.png)

Comment: that's a very old blog post. you are much better off using the official quickstart: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#quickstart - or if maven is too hard, just use the ZIP release: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/ZIP-Release

Comment: Agreed and thanks for your reply, That issue is resolved but can you help with fixing up karate-config.js file issue. Here the issue is the file is not considered as Java script even though if i add functions properly.

Comment: sorry I can't help with that unless you follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue